# how to xpath field before <label for="street" string="Address"/>

Tags: xpath, odoo

i want to xpath "field_name" before `<label for="street" string="Address"/>`
but i can xpath just label :'(

```
<xpath expr="//label[@for='street']" position="after">  
    <field name="field_name"/>
</xpath
```

Some one please help me and thank you for you time to reading my word

Comment: Do you have a sample input HTML document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, You can give position like after, before, attributes

```
<xpath expr="//label[@string='Address']" position="before">  
    <field name="field_name"/>
</xpath>
```

`OR` You can use another way like

```
<label for="street" position="before">
    <field name="field_name"/>
    <label for="field_name"/>
</label>
```

Comment: if that isn't what you want, please give us more detail on your problem (inherited view, what your output should look like, and so on) :-)

Answer (score 2):

For this kinds of problems (where you don't have a name reference), you have to play with paths. Let's say that you have your label in an structure like this:

```
<form>
    <sheet>
        <div>
            <label string='street'/>
            <label string='postal code'/>
        <div>
    </sheet>
</form>
```

Now, you need to reach the firs label, so you can do something like this:

```
<xpath expr='//sheet/div/label[1]' position="after">
    <field name="field_name"/>
</xpath>
```

Explanation:
With the expression, we're calling, in first place, the relative path of the first sheet we have (// are for relative path), so we can reach it anywhere in the code, second the absolute path of that div (/ is for absolute path) and finally, since we have to labels, but we want the second one, we use [1] to get it. This exact path is not always necessary, I am just suggesting it because usually we have multiples divs, but just one sheet, that's why I took it to be the root, but of course you have to adapt this to your own structure. For more information about xpath, you can read https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp